# AngularJS ng-Change open link in new tab using ctrl + click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codemirror

I have created a jsfiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/2m6cbrtu/7/)

but I am not able to figure out how to implement ctrl+click on the select options.

in the project js file after calling `retrieveSelectedClass`, I have some http request to get the data from server side and display it in ui. I am using a library to display the code, `Codemirror`.

```
        var data = {
            apexClassName: $scope.selectedName.name
        };
        var config = {
            params: data
        };
        $http.get("/getApexBody", config).then(getApexBodyCallback, getApexBodyErrorCallback);

        function getApexBodyCallback(response) {
            if (response.data) {
                $scope.apexClassWrapper = response.data;
                if (globalEditor1) {
                    globalEditor1.toTextArea();
                }
                setTimeout(function(test) {
                    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('apexBody'), {
                        lineNumbers: true,
                        matchBrackets: true,
                        styleActiveLine: true,
                        extraKeys: {
                            ".": function(editor) {
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    editor.execCommand("autocomplete");
                                }, 100);
                                throw CodeMirror.Pass; // tell CodeMirror we didn't handle the key
                            }
                        },
                        gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
                        lint: true,
                        mode: "text/x-apex"
                    });
                    editor.markClean();
                    editor.on("keyup", function(cm, event) {
                        var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
                        if (!ExcludedIntelliSenseTriggerKeys[(event.keyCode || event.which).toString()]) {
                            if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
                            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                editor.showHint({
                                    hint: CodeMirror.hint.auto,
                                    completeSingle: false
                                });
                            }, 150);
                        }
                    });
                    globalEditor1 = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
                }), 2000
                document.getElementById('saveBtn').style.visibility = 'visible';
                $scope.isPaneShown = false;
            }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}')" ng-options="item.name group by item.groupName for item in names"
            class="code-helper" id="code-helperId">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div style="padding: 1px; position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 30px; bottom: 30px; width: 100%; height: auto; " loading-pane="isPaneShown">
<textarea ng-model="apexClassWrapper.body" id="apexBody" name="apexBody" style="display: none;" readonly="true">{{apexClassWrapper.body}}</textarea>

</div>
```

The issue is even if I catch the ctrl click event like this:

```
if ($window.event.ctrlKey) {}
```

inside my `retrieveSelectedClass`, how will it open same html page in the new tab with the option value already selected in the selection menu

But I am not able to understand how will I implement ctrl+click on the option select value to get it open in a new tab, with the file name selected in the selection dropdown and the text area showing the body of the retrieved class?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To open a new tab when the value in the select has changed?

Comment: yes, I would like to open the selected option when we do a ctrl+click in a new tab and the selection option should be selected already in the new tab's select dropdown.

Comment: You cannot open a new tab on the user's browser for security purposes. Imagine those fishy websites opening 100 tabs lol. Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript) with a lot of info.